# How pass variable from Python to Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

How to change this command in Powershell to work with Python:

```
$route = Get-NetRoute | Where-Object { $_.NextHop -eq $defaultGateway }
$ip, $mask = $route.DestinationPrefix -split '/'
```

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
route = subprocess.run(f"powershell.exe Get-NetRoute | Where-Object {{ $_.NextHop -eq '{default_gateway}' }}", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).decode("utf-8")
ip, mask = route.split("/")[0], route.split("/")[1]
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error, just an empty 'ip' variable

Comment: Does the `route` variable have any data?

Comment: No data in 'route'

Comment: Does the `subprocess.run` work if you write it to STDOUT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```python
import subprocess, base64

default_gateway = "1.2.3.4"  # Replace with your value

# The PowerShell script, as formatted triple-single-quoted string which 
# can span multiple lines.
command = f'''
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
Get-NetRoute | Where-Object NextHop -eq '{default_gateway}' | ForEach-Object DestinationPrefix
'''

# Encode the command in UTF-16 LE, then Base-64 for PowerShell
commandBase64 = base64.b64encode( command.encode("utf-16-le") ).decode()

# Run the encoded PowerShell command and capture its output
proc = subprocess.run( f"powershell.exe -EncodedCommand {commandBase64}", capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8", shell=True)

if proc.returncode == 0:
    ip, mask = proc.stdout.strip().split("/")
    print(f"IP: {ip}, mask: {mask}")
else:
    print(f"ERROR: {proc.stderr}")
```

- The safest way to call PowerShell from another language like Python is to use the `powershell.exe -EncodedCommand` parameter, which accepts a **Base-64** encoded Unicode string. The Unicode encoding must be **UTF-16 LE**. This avoids all the hassles with parameter quoting.
- `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` ensures that PowerShell actually outputs UTF-8.
- `ForEach-Object DestinationPrefix` outputs the value of the `DestinationPrefix` property only. Otherwise you would get the formatted, *for-display-only* output of `Get-NetRoute`, which is not suitable for programmatic processing.
- `subprocess.run()` returns a [`CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object

  - The `stdout` property contains the actual output of PowerShell.
  - Likewise, the `stderr` property contains the error output of PowerShell.
  - Make sure to check the `returncode` property to determine success or failure of PowerShell.